# Dual blending - Radeon's issue

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, fragment-shader

I am trying to write a shader that uses dual source blending. Everything works fine with nVidia, but fails on Radeon 7800 (with latest drivers - 14.12).
My GLSL shader:

```
layout ( location = 0 ) out vec3 O_RT0 ; 
layout ( location = 1 ) out vec3 O_RT1 ; 
void main()
{
    //filling O_RT0 and O_RT1 with some data
}
```

At this stage I've got FBO with one color attachment and called 
glDrawBuffers with 1 as number of outputs and GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 as target.

I am using following blend function: `src = GL_ONE, dst = GL_SRC1_COLOR, src_alpha = GL_ONE, dst_alpha = GL_ONE`

What's more https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending#Dual_Source_Blending says that I should bind outputs with `index` keyword:
`layout(location = 0, index = 0) out vec4 outputColor0;
layout(location = 0, index = 1) out vec4 outputColor1;`

It does not help.
AMD's results looks like nVidia's but with following blendfunc: `src = GL_ONE, dst = GL_ZERO, src_alpha = GL_ONE, dst_alpha = GL_ZERO`

So I assume that something wrong is happening with second output.

Extension GL_ARB_blend_func_extended is supported on both cards.
They also returns `GL_MAX_DUAL_SOURCE_DRAW_BUFFERS = 1`

I think that problem is somewhere with binding outputs. Is it possible that calling glDrawBuffers(1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0) is interpreted as "ignore this: `( location = 1 ) out vec3 O_RT1`" which causes blending with src1 == zeros?

Comment: why you need dual blending? cannot you achieve same functionality in alternative way?

Comment: Better performance. I know that it can be done in alternative way, but it is the last thing that I'm gonna do.

Comment: provided that is your bottleneck, if you can't get it working on AMD you have 2 choices: you fix on AMD in alternative way and you ends up maintaining 2 different source codes, or you wait AMD bugfix (unless AMD is already right and it is just nvidia being more permissive here)breaking your application for the 30%(or whatever % they are) of people having AMD hardware.

Tried to use `glBindFragDataLocationIndexed` ?

Comment: Yes, i've tried `glBindFragDataLocationIndexed`. No differences. I just wanted to make sure that I'm doing everything correctly (binding, setting blend func etc). Maybe there is an error in my code that is ignored on nVidia, but breakes AMD.

Comment: I fear its amd bug, up to you working around only for AMD or just change approach for both AMD and NVIDIA (have you alredy tried on Intel)?
right now I can't get it working on my card but I'm limited up to GL 3.3